# Read log file from another server and display in listing in php - laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to read log file from another server and display log listing in Laravel.

I am trying to read log file from another server to my current server, but I am not able to read the file.

I have tried all php file functions, but they all ended with the same results.

Comment: Update your attempt code in the question.

Comment: I am used below code to copy file from remote server to local server 

       $remote_file_url = 'Remote server url';        
         
        $local_file = 'local file url';
       
        $copy = copy($remote_file_url, $local_file);
        
        if (!$copy) {
            echo "Doh! failed to copy ...\n";
        } else {
            echo "WOOT! success to copy ...\n";
        }

NOTE : Using above code i am able to copy file from remote server  xampp directory but not able to copy from server root(home) directory.